# How to use NSubstitute to mock a lazy class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, lazy-evaluation, nsubstitute

```
//Assert
Lazy<INotificationService> notificationService = Substitute.For<Lazy<INotificationService>>();
Service target = new Service(repository, notificationService);

//Act
target.SendNotify("Message");

//Arrange
notificationService.Received().Value.sendNotification(null, null, null, null);
```

The above code throws an exception.

> The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor

I am using C# 4.0 and NSubstitute 1.2.1

Comment: Do really want to substitute the Lazy<Xyz>? I would just assume that Lazy<> works und use the Value Factory constructor of it, providing Substitute.For<Xyz>() as Value Factory...

Comment: +1 to @sanosdole's comment. Have posted that answer as a community wiki.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per @sanosdole's comment, I would suggest using a real `Lazy` instance to return your substitute. Something like:

```
var notificationService = Substitute.For<INotificationService>();
var target = new Service(repository, new Lazy<INotificationService>(() => notificationService));

target.SendNotify("Message");

notificationService.ReceivedWithAnyArgs().sendNotification(null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Bingo - works for me in conjunction with sanosdole comment above